# 'Specified cast is not valid' in LAMBDA expression when querying float field

Tags: c#, .net, linq, lambda

I can not understand why *"Specified cast is not valid exception"* is thrown here:

**c# code:**

the exception  throws when it reaches to  `m.HadapGoalPercent` property, i tryed to change the datatype of `x => x.Field<float>("HadapGoalPercent")` also to single and double but its not working

```
 for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
                    {
                        Sales.Month m = new Sales.Month(Yearnum, (byte)(i+1));
                        m.HadapGoal = dt.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.Field<int>("MonthNum") == i + 1).Select(x => x.Field<int>("HadapGoalIncome")).Single();
                        m.ShotefGoal = dt.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.Field<int>("MonthNum") == i + 1).Select(x => x.Field<int>("ShotefGoalIncome")).Single();
                        m.HadapGoalPercent = dt.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.Field<int>("MonthNum") == i + 1).Select( x => x.Field<float>("HadapGoalPercent")).SingleOrDefault();
                        m.ShotefGoalPercent = dt.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.Field<int>("MonthNum") == i + 1).Select(x => x.Field<float>("ShotefGoalPercent")).SingleOrDefault();
                        months.Add(m);
                    }
```

**thats the definitions** of `ShotefGoalPercent` and `HadapGoalPercent`  properties inside Month Class:

```
 public Single ShotefGoalPercent { get; set; }
 public Single HadapGoalPercent { get; set; }
```

**thats dt datatable:**

(HadapGoalPercent and ShotefGoalPercent are defined as decimal(5,4) in sql database)

[image: dt Datatable Image]

thank you very much for your time and considiration

Comment: Have you tried casting to decimal? After all, you said it's stored in the DB as a decimal.

Comment: Take a look at `dt.Columns["HadapGoalPercent"].DataType` property. It should tell you what cast you need to use.

Comment: ok...thanks to @sr28 the problem was solved i have changed HadapGoalPercent , ShotefGoalPercent  from single to decimal and the datatatpe in query to decimal also...its working. here is a thread i found now about the difference between decimal, float, single and double: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/618535/difference-between-decimal-float-and-double-in-net.   why not write it as an answer? - thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my comment I'm not sure why you aren't just casting as a decimal, as that's what you've stored it as in the DB. However, if you really want this as a double you can try:

```
Convert.ToDouble(value)
```

With the size of decimals you're passing in you should be fine. With very large decimals you run the risk of losing precision, but as I say, I don't think this will be an issue for you.